# Java netbeans not all text shown on JFrame using tokenizer and using of for loop

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

Hello i have written this code, but it only prints out everything in console and not in my JFrame, anyone knows what i did wrong? thank you!

```
  if(selectedValue.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
        {
          displayRecords.setText("You have selected index 0");

          for(int i=0; i<vList.size(); i++) {
               String tokenizerValue = vList.get(i).toString(); 

                System.out.println(tokenizerValue);
                textArea.setText(tokenizerValue);
           }
        }
```

Comment: call `textArea.append(tokenizerValue + "\n");` **not** `.setText(...)`. Else everything in the for loop will be over-written except for the last line. As always, read the [JTextArea Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) first.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Omg. Thank you soo much!